# unable to get property 'setActionableButtonState' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am getting a script error when running the following script on IE11.

Error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'setActionableButtonState' of undefined or null reference
File: infoall.js, Line: 995, Column: 3
```

My code:

```
function setInfoActionableButtonState(enable)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.names.length; ++i)
    {
        var frame = rs.getPane(sections.names[i]);
        if(typeof frame.setActionableButtonState != "undefined" && frame.setActionableButtonState != null)
        {
            try
            {
                frame.setActionableButtonState(enable);
            }
            catch(e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code in text format, not screenshots.

Comment: @Uzbekjon sorry about that, took out the image and put it in text format.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that your `frame` variable is `null` or `undefined`. You probably want to check that `frame` is set before checking it's `setActionableButtonState` property.

```
//          |- === HERE ===
if(typeof frame != "undefined" && typeof frame.setActionableButtonState != "undefined" && ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do I insert that line you gave me before the current line of code, or do i replace it completely?

Comment: Just add `typeof frame != "undefined" && ` at the begging of your current `if` statement.